# The use of "/" meaning

Tags: symbols

In an instance of "Signature/Stamp", does the **/** mean signature **and** stamp or  is the meaning signature **or** stamp

Comment: Your question title conflicts, slightly, with the question asked in the body. The forward slash has a few other uses apart from giving readers a choice of one or the other option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The slash is most commonly used as the word substitute for "or" which indicates a choice (often mutually-exclusive) is present.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_%28punctuation%29)

Comment: Some people have started pronouncing it like the word *slash*, adding a new coordinator to the English language.

Answer (score 1):

I am a habitually user of the forward slash.  I don't find it meaning "or" in general writing (maybe on surveys or things you fill out).  I would define it as either grouping different things or it can be used to convey different contextual terms for one meaning.

**Grouping:**

"We are going to do the swim/bike/race triathlon."  It is one single event but has 3 sub-events.   The "or" usage would not work here.

**Context and meaning:**

I am shooting an email out to 3 different groups.  One group has defined our project as CMS.  The other two define it as DMS.  So I can say, "Let me know when we are going to meet to discuss CMS/DMS solutions."  There isn't a group because it is just one project but the one project has different names and the sentence above would be understood by all three groups (hopefully).

Comment: Wikipedia backs your usage (which happens to be mine too)"The slash is also used to avoid taking a position in a naming controversy, allowing the juxtaposition of both names without stating a preference" But in the OP's question, the answer is *or*.